# Symfony 3 +__isInitialized__: false

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I have this problem when i get my object , just the id is true , other information are false 
the code is :

```html
 public function listetacheAction($id)
     {
          $em = $this-> getDoctrine() -> getManager();
           $Projet=$em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Projet')->find($id);
        $Tache=$Projet->getTaches();
dump($Projet);
die(); }
```

screen the dump :
[Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAAbG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a proxy of your real entity class. It's not initialized yet, because you told doctrine not to fetch it... until your code try to access to it.

If you don't want lazy loading, just change the fetching behavior to be eager. Documentation to understand how to do it: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html